# Installing command view on HP-UX

Tags: hp-ux

I have just setup a new Itanium server and installed HP-UX 11i v3. OS installed fine and is up and running. I need some input on what is happening with my file name. I have a .depot file on a cd and i am attempting to install it. The file name show as CVSDM_~1.DEP;1. Why is there a tilde and a semicolon? It wont allow me to do anything with this file. It gives me the message cannot access....No such file or directory.

I am attempted to copy the file from cdrom to /tmp directory with cp command.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to unmount the CD and mount it with command like:

```
mount -o cdcase /dev/dsk/cXtXdX /cdrom
```

This will prevent from shorten the filenames.